# Why should I create setup project

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, installation

When I am creating projects in `VS` I only add a set up project to my solution if it is a service (I can't get it running without installing it first).

If the prorgam isn't a service I don't normally create a set up project but rather copy the .exe file as well as all the necessary `dlls` for the application to run to a desired folder and I run the application from there.

My question is if there is any benefit in terms of performance or anything else when you install a program (through its set up) rather than just running it without having it first installed it

Comment: If you need setup - build it, otherwise - don't. I'm not exactly sure what kind of advice you are looking for...

Comment: I am asking if there is any benefit in terms of performance or anything else when you install a program (through its set up) rather than just running it withot having it first installed it

Comment: I could not get that from your post... Consider to edit your post instead of comment.

Comment: @apomene Setup programs are for ease of use by users, easy to distribute, easy to install, easy to uninstall It has nothing to do with code or performance.

Answer (score 4):

It highly depends on needs of your application. You may for instance:

- Add necessary registry entries
- Register file extensions to your application
- Check prerequisites and (potentially) install missing libraries or frameworks
- Check for potential problems, which will disallow your application to work correctly
- Allow user to choose only subset of features your application offers (thus making the installation smaller)
- Choose binary and library files for specific environment (for example 32 vs 64-bit). For example, NVidia now gives you one unified installer for a series of graphics cards and then installer chooses the appropriate ones to install.
- Automatically add shortcuts to start menu/screen and desktop

You can of course embed most of these actions in your application, but I'd vote against that. That's because your application would have some boilerplate code, which would run only once, or even your application might not start because of missing requirements, which setup application might have resolved.

Also, it's less user friendly. With setup program, users may very quickly prepare application to work and also - equally quickly - remove the program from their computer (along with all config files, registry entries etc.).

If you plan to use the program only by yourself, it's your choice. But if you want to publish your program, I'd suggest at least making an option to either install program or use it in the portable mode (without installation).

Answer (score 1):

I think there are benefits of having setup project from end-user and developer perspective as well. Normally when you finish your project you want to easily distribute it. End users are rather used to downloading and installing application in a common way meaning:

- selecting the destination path
- select whether to install for all or only current user
- checking whether to create desktop/programs menu icons or not
- lunch the program after installation

and this can be easily accomplished by setup project.

I think regular user finds hard to let's say

- download compressed file
- extract package (assuming that appropriate for doing it is already
  installed. In other  case it is required to install it)
- create dektop shortcut